# Applying impulse to an SKSpriteNode to give it a random direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode

I have a ball that bounces around the screen. Based on the level the user has made it to, I make the ball go faster. So, I did the following:

```
[ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:[self vectorForLevel:self.level]];
```

The method for building the `CGVector`.

```
- (CGVector)vectorForLevel:(int)level {
    CGFloat thrust = level+3;
    return CGVectorMake(thrust*cosf(4), thrust*sinf(-4));
}
```

While this works really well and speeds up for each level like I want to, I would also like to randomize the angle that the balls starts at, but I am not sure how to do that.

I don't understand enough about `CGVector` to really know how to change the angle. Are the 4 and -4 that I threw in there the angle?

**Does anyone know how to randomize the direction?**

Comment: Just change the angles...

Comment: @JoshCaswell Stupid question. Are the 4 and -4 I used the angles? I just threw those in there and it worked fairly well.

Comment: Yes, those are the angles. Your expressions there are conversions from polar to cartesian: x = r * cos(theta), y = r * sin(theta). r being radius and theta angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expressions you're using inside `CGVectorMake()` are essentially a conversion from polar coordinates to cartesian.

The *x* component is given by `radius * cos(theta)`, where *theta* is the angle in radians. *y* is `radius * sin(theta)`. Zero angle generally points to the right ("due east").

Thus, just change *theta* to change the direction of your vector. (It's most sensible to pass the same number to both `cosf()` and `sinf()`, but of course you'll get *some* result no matter what you use.)